# How can I count tickets by these 2 dates?

Tags: excel, pivot, reporting, netsuite

I need to create something to track when a ticket is created and when it is closed, grouped by weeks. The challenge here is that a ticket can take days or weeks to close and I need to be able to differentiate that count somehow.

For example, my data looks like this:

```
Week | Date Created | Date Closed
 1       5/1/2018      5/2/2018
 2       5/10/2018     5/17/2018
```

And my final product needs to look like:

```
Week | # Created | # Closed
 1          1          1
 2          1          0
 3          0          1
```

This is not possible in NetSuite so I've been trying to replicate it in Excel but I'm still hitting a wall. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this even SQL?

Comment: It's more of a general problem that's not restricted to any language. The tool to solving it isn't so important as to actually solving it. If it can be done via SQL, I can understand the general idea and try to reproduce the solution in Excel/ NetSuite/ PLSQL/ etc.

Comment: Convert your dates to week numbers and it should be pretty straightforward from there.  The "week" column in your original data seems redundant?

Comment: You're right, the week column in the original data isn't actually there, I typed it in by accident. Some edge cases makes this less straight forward though: a ticket can be closed with no other tickets created that week, a ticket can not be closed yet so it will be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

TeeWee,

On the main dataset worksheet you want to add 2 columns that calculate the week number for the open closed dates using the WEEKNUM function

```
=WEEKNUM(cell with date)
```

eg. =WEEKNUM(B2)
Sheet2 (Ticket Info): [image: Sheet2]

Then on the worksheet with the stats you want to do the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF(column with open or close date, cell with week number)
```

eg. =COUNTIF(Sheet2!D:D,Sheet1!$A2)
Sheet1(Stats): [image: Sheet1]

Please note this will calculate the week numbers based on annual week numbers so a change int he year will cause the count to reset and therefore a ticket crossing over years will need additional handling (maybe a year/week no id)

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. However, this requires the week numbers to be populated manually. In the data, it's possible to have a week  where there were only tickets closed and no tickets opened. (holiday week, but people working from home are still closing tickets).

Comment: I think you'll struggle to do it in a single formula without doing the above. I could be wrong :s

Answer (score 0):

Screen detail with instruction below data; no restriction on crossing years

Screen View with details

[image]